# How to use the relative path in SQL - ODBC?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, odbc

I have a problem with Excel (ODBC / Access). I would like to refresh data from any folder in my computer. I have file which I use from Desktop, but I would like to refresh data from the same file when it will be move to documents, etc. Please could you provide what I should do?

I have a file connection as below:

`DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Task1\SalesBudget2018.xlsx;DefaultDir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Task1;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;`

Thank you.

EDIT1: Thank you. I tried use your solution and I received error: "run time error 2147467259 Database or object is read-only", my code below. The bug is related to ".Open" line:

```
Sub RefreshData()

Dim CreateNew As Object
Dim RunSELECT As Object
Dim Data As String
Dim SQL As String

FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.path

Path = Left(FolderPath, InStrRev(FolderPath, "\") - 1)

Set CreateNew = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With CreateNew
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Path & "\SalesBudget2018.xlsx" & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"";"
    .Open
End With

'Run SQL

SQL = "SELECT * FROM [twRynki$]"
Set RunSELECT = cn.Execute(SQL)
Do
   output = output & RunSELECT(0) & ";" & RunSELECT(1) & ";" & RunSELECT(2) & vbNewLine
   Debug.Print RunSELECT(0); ";" & RunSELECT(1) & ";" & RunSELECT(2)
   rs.Movenext
Loop Until rs.EOF
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path actually is not relative at all. But ACE/JET data engine does not support relative paths anyway.
A relative path  would be

\Data\mydb.mdb

So, above would be one folder up called data from current location.  And one folder down using relative would be:

..\Data\mydb.mdb

However, with ACE/Access relative  paths are not supported. However, what we do when we want software to work say from the current folder? We simple get and use the full path name ON APPLICATION start up. So, you can get/grab the current folder. In Excel VBA you  can use this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

So above will give you the current path. And thus you use that in code to set the connection string. So, even in access, if we want the software to work in any  folder?  We simply get/grab the full path name on startup. As a result, the software works in any folder and you effective  get relative address in that you "don't care" where the software is placed, since you always get/grab the full path name anyway. So, with above, you could append a folder name called data

```
ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Data\Mydb.accdb"
```

So, from the current workbook location, you  could always have a folder called data, and inside that folder you can have your database. So, in effect you do get relative addressing, but you always pulling the full path name of the current workbook as per above.
The end result is you don't miss not having some form of relative addressing since you don't need to with this approach.

The above is for Excel VBA. To get current path from Access VBA? You can use this:

```
currentproject.Path
```

So, your connection string to Excel could be this:

```
dim strExcelPath   as string
strExcelPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Task1\SalesBudget2018.xlsx"
```

It not clear if the access application is in the SAME folder as task1?
Assuming yes, then this would work:

```
strExcelPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\SalesBudget2018.xlsx"
```

So, now the folder can be on the desktop, my documents - it will not matter. You can thus use above as part of your connection string. It not clear if you linking to Excel (linked table), or you using VBA and say ADO code. However, it really don't matter. On application startup, you get the above connection string, check it against the linked table -- if same then do nothing. If different, then you re-link that one table. Thus you ONLY re-link one time if the folder been moved. And no matter where you move the folder? As long as you assume the Excel sheet is in the same folder as the access app, then you good to go. And as noted, you could add a sub folder say ExcelSheets to above. And once again, no matter where you move this folder with the Access part, as long as the sub folder is in the same dir/folder, then this will work - despite you not having relative addressing.

Comment: Hi, please could you check my "Edit1" under question? Your solution works, thank you, but I received another error and my not sure how deal with it.

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.path does NOT have a trailing \, so insterrev will return 0 - your chopping off the path name.